# I want to validate my numbers with regex before using it but it not working out

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate my numbers with regex before using it but it not working out

I want the first digit to start with **0** follow by **2 or 5** and follow by **4** and the rest continue to **10** digit

```
<?php
$str = "0241310102";
$pattern = "([0]{1}[2,5]{1}[4]{1}[0-9]{7})";

if(preg_match($pattern, $str)){
echo "YES";
}else{
echo "NO";
}

?>
```

Comment: Patterns need delimiters in PHP. You don't get any errors with this? `{1}` is almost also useless, as the data written before it already means that. `/^0[25]4\d{7}$/` is possibly what you want.

Comment: Try `/^0[25]4\d{7}$/`

Comment: Do you really want to have `,` in `[2,5]`? That will match a literal comma in the number. To match either `2` or `5` you just write `[25]`.

Comment: Good for testing and even explains whats going on https://regex101.com/

Comment: What is not working out in the current code?

Comment: @user3783243 Parentheses are valid delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to anchor the pattern to the start/end of the string (`^`, `$`).
2. Single digits do not need to be specified as a character class `[0]` → `0`
3. Quantifier need only to be specified if different from one `0{1}` → `0`
4. `[2,5]` would include the comma in the character class → `[25]`

```php
$examples = [
    "0241310102",
    "1241310102",
    "0541310102",
    "0551310102",
    "0241"
];
$pattern = '(^0[25]4[0-9]{7}$)';

foreach ($examples as $example) {
    echo $example, ": ";
    if (preg_match($pattern, $example)) {
        echo "YES", "\n";
    } else {
        echo "NO", "\n";
    }
}
```